# Force close if no internet connection or URL malformed while fetching JSON data

Tags: android, json, exception

hey,
i'm new to android and i'm having a little problem. I'm running an asynctask to fetch json data from the web in the background. this works well, however the app force closes when theres no internet connection or theres an error with the json parsing or the URL is malformed. is there a way to show a custom error instead of force closing the app? and of course keep the app open. here is my simplyfied code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    public static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new LongOperation(Main.this).execute();
    }


    class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private Main longOperationContext = null;
        private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;

        public LongOperation(Main context) {
            longOperationContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

          //JSON Fetching and parsing here

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                alertbox.setTitle("Error");
                alertbox.setMessage("URL Exception");
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
                alertbox.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                alertbox.setTitle("Error");
                alertbox.setMessage("IO Exception");
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
                alertbox.show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                alertbox.setTitle("Error");
                alertbox.setMessage("JSON Exception");
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
                alertbox.show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //...
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
      //...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

EDIT:
here is the logcat:

```
02-22 19:33:47.881: WARN/dalvikvm(683): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:59)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:786)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:801)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at en.android.albumdownloader.Main$LongOperation.doInBackground(Main.java:130)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at en.android.albumdownloader.Main$LongOperation.doInBackground(Main.java:1)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
02-22 19:33:47.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(683):     ... 4 more
02-22 19:33:47.881: WARN/ActivityManager(71):   Force finishing activity en.android.albumdownloader/.Main
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683): Activity en.android.albumdownloader.Main has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4057bdf0 that was originally added here
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity en.android.albumdownloader.Main has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4057bdf0 that was originally added here
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at en.android.albumdownloader.Main$LongOperation.onPreExecute(Main.java:174)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at en.android.albumdownloader.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:56)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-22 19:33:51.822: ERROR/WindowManager(683):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: edited the main post with the logcat

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a dialog from the background thread; you have to do that from the UI thread or you'll be causing yet another exception in your `catch` clause (I'd imagine your logcat says something like "show() can only be called from the UI thread"). You'll have to catch the exception and store some sort of member variable in the AsyncTask, then show the error dialog in onPostExecute (or trigger it in onProgressUpdate).

Comment: ok i get that, but it still force closes without the dialogs. any ideas why?

Comment: that traceback indicates you're still trying to show the dialog in the doInBackground method. As I said, you can't do that; that's the background thread. You have to catch the exception, then show the error dialog in the onPostExecute, *not* in doInBackground or anything else directly called from that thread (or use a Handler to manually post back to the main thread, but I'd avoid messing with that unless you know what you're doing).